# How to pass var's to another page using jquery & php

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to pass my form var's to anothe page..

```
var login = $('#login').val();
var pass = $('#pass').val();
var data = {
    login: login,
    pass: pass
};

$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    url: "page_2.php",
    success: function(data)
    {
        document.location.href = url;

    }
});
```

It doesn't post to the new page at all..  In page_2.php I have:

```
<?php
        $error = false;


        if (isset($_REQUEST))
        {
            extract($_REQUEST);   
            print_r($_REQUEST);
        }
//      else
//      {
//              header("location:page_1.php");
//      }

?>
```

I've searched google for 2 days with no luck on examples of posting var's to another page via jquery/ajax/php..  Can anyone help or point me to a link that can?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Why do you want to use Ajax for this when you are changing the page's URL in the success callback anyway? Why not use a simple form?

Answer (score 1):

Dennis,

After submitting a form, if you want to take the user to a page using that new data, you don't want to use Ajax. Just set the "action" attribute on your `<form>` to 'page_2.php', and be on your way. You don't even need Javascript for this situation.

```
<form method="post" action="page_2.php">
  <!-- your form fields go here -->
</form>
```

---

If you *do* need to use Ajax in the future, I have a few suggestions. Run Firebug (for Firefox) or Webkit's Developer Tools (for Safari or Chrome) to examine the Ajax requests being sent, and if/why they are failing. You've got the right idea, but it's possible that your data is never making it to page_2 (e.g. bad URL, a Javascript error elsewhere that prevents the $.ajax from being run, etc.)

Simplify your Ajax submission using [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). Combine this with [`jQuery.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to gather all of the form data for you, and bind this as a submit handler for your `<form>`. For example:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  var url = 'page_2.php';
  $.post(url, $(this).serialize(), function( data ) {
    console.log("Success!\nData: " + data);
  });
  return false;
});
```

On the PHP end, you have the right idea. I recommend using `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST` to reduce the possibility of a CSRF.

Answer (score 1):

@Dennis -

IOW, you are trying to save state from one page to be utilized on the 2nd page.

The proper way to do this is to post data via form submission. You can do it with an ajax request, but you add un-needed complexity to your code. Use AJAX for when you need to pass data to the server, but want to stay on the same page.

Follow Blackcoat's recommendation. **Form Submission**

Remember if all you have is a hammer, then your going to be whacking everything including your thumb. Always go with the simple solution first.

Answer (score 0):

the `url` variable is not known to the `success` callback function...

try alerting something `alert(data);` inside the success function to see if it get called..

Comment: that was my last try.. I did try using  document.location.href = "./page_2.php";

Comment: Tried the "alert(data); and got Array
(
    [login] => dennis@test.com
    [pass] => testpass
    [__utma] => 184037297.1763131186.1271628080.1273616918.1275392275.3
    [__utmz] => 184037297.1271628080.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
    [__unam] => 8a516e-128897be867-32a12505-2
)
So it is sending to the page but when it redirects it does so without sending..

Comment: When the page loads, the extract($_REQUEST) only has Array
2(
3 [__utma] => 184037297.1763131186.1271628080.1273616918.1275392275.3
4 [__utmz] => 184037297.1271628080.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
5 [__unam] => 8a516e-128897be867-32a12505-2
6)

Comment: @Dennis, the final redirect will not post the data.. the ajax call will send the data, execute the page, and bring back to the current page the results.. changing the location just sends the browser to the new url (*like clicking on a link*) and that is considered a GET, so only solution is to pass them to the url..

Comment: I need to send some form data to the next page when I pass them to the new URL..  :(

Comment: @Dennis, as @Pekka mentioned in his comment and all the other answers to your question, why not use a form and submit it to the next page and scrap the ajax call altogether (*as it seems to not be what you want... the ajax call works fine and sends the data ..*)